# Cruce de tablas en sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo dos tablas, una de ellas es un `calendario` y en la segunda tabla tengo registros de `días` que son *festivos locales*.

Ambas tablas tienen los mismos campos y entre esos campos, uno hace referencia a las distintas fechas y otro de ellos es un campo tipo `bit` que indica si es *festivo o no* (todos los registros de la segunda tabla tienen este campo con **valor 1**).

Consulta para obtener datos de la tabla 1:

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM [dbo].[tCalendarioFestivosNacionales] AS FN
WHERE 
    CONVERT(DATE,FN.PK_Date) BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()-5) AND CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()+5)
ORDER BY FN.PK_Date ASC
```

Tabla 1 (Calendario):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla 2 (Tabla festivos locales):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede observar con la imágenes, el día 27 de octubre ha sido establecido como festivo local y por lo tanto, con la consulta que se muestra anteriormente, me gustaría obtener el mismo resultado pero con el día 27 como festivo, es decir, obtener ese registro de la segunda tabla.

No consigo hacer esa superposición de registros en mi consulta con lo que todo tipo de ayuda es bienvenida.

Comment: Revisa [¿Cómo crear un ejemplo verificable?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Así, es más que probable, que obtengas la ayuda solicitada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una estrategia es unir dos consultas. En la primera obtienes los registros (festivos nacionales) que no están en la segunda (festivos locales) y lo unes
(mediante un UNION ALL) con los de los festivos locales.

```
SELECT
    PK_Date, biFestivo
FROM [dbo].[tCalendarioFestivosNacionales] AS FN
WHERE 
    CONVERT(DATE,FN.PK_Date) BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()-5) AND CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()+5)
AND PK_Date not in (
  SELECT PK_Date 
  FROM [dbo].[tCalendarioFestivosLocales]
)
UNION ALL
SELECT
    PK_Date, biFestivo
FROM [dbo].[tCalendarioFestivosLocales] AS FN
WHERE 
    CONVERT(DATE,FN.PK_Date) BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()-5) AND CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()+5)
```

Si le quieres dar un orden al resultado de la unión:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        PK_Date, biFestivo
    FROM [dbo].[tCalendarioFestivosNacionales] AS FN
    WHERE 
        CONVERT(DATE,FN.PK_Date) BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()-5) AND CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()+5)
    AND PK_Date not in (
      SELECT PK_Date 
      FROM [dbo].[tCalendarioFestivosLocales]
    )
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        PK_Date, biFestivo
    FROM [dbo].[tCalendarioFestivosLocales] AS FN
    WHERE 
        CONVERT(DATE,FN.PK_Date) BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()-5) AND CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()+5)
) a
ORDER BY PK_Date
```

Comment: Genial, funciona perfectamente. Muchas gracias